# AVR ADC performance: interrupts vs. manual conversion

Tags: avr, adc, uart, interrupts, performance

I have a device on ATMega16 microcontroller that is supposed to constantly send ADC measurement results over USART. The controller is operating at 16MHz with an external crystal and ADC prescaler is set to 128. I have tried two methods of performing ADC conversion and sending the results.

1. The first method is based on interrupts

```c
    int main(void) {
        ...
        while (true) {}
    }

    ISR(ADC_vect) {
        USARTSendByte(ADCL);
        USARTSendByte(ADCH);
        ADCSRA |= 1 << ADSC;
    }
```

1. The second method is based on manually starting the conversion

```c
    int main(void) {
        ... 
        // main loop
        while (true) {
            if (adcEnabled) {
                ADMUX |= channel;
                ADCSRA |= (1 << ADSC);
                while (!(ADCSRA & (1 << ADIF))) {
                    // Do nothing
                }
                ADCSRA |= (1 << ADIF); // Clear ADIF            
                USARTSendByte(ADCL);
                USARTSendByte(ADCH);
            }
        }
    }
```

I've performed a number of tests which consisted of sending 32 blocks of 512 bytes (16384 bytes in total) over USART and measuring transmission time. In the first case (interrupts) the average time was `1623.13ms`. The smallest result was 1535ms and the largest - 1712ms. In the second case the result was `1600.38ms` which is  22.75ms less than in previous case, with a smallest result of 1530ms and the largest result of 1679ms.

So the question is: will interrupts actually decrease ADC performance and why is that happening or the results of my tests were inconclusive?

Comment: note, that you can check for ADSC flag in ADCSRA - the micro changes it to 0 after conversion is done, this way you don't have to clear the interrupt flag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're probably measuring is the overhead of entering and exiting the ISR in software. Because you haven't decorated the ISR it is saving the entire register state and restoring it on return. Your ISR can be declared to be naked and you can manage the preservation of the SREG and other critical registers yourself (e.g. in inline assembly) and that will get you where you want to be.

You don't really want to be calling functions from the ISR either. Just move bytes into a global buffer and do stuff with the buffered data from your main loop (like send them out over the UART).

From the [avr-gcc](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__interrupts.html) manual:

> define ISR_NAKED
>
> ISR is created with no prologue or epilogue code. The user code is responsible for preservation of the machine state
>   including the SREG register, as well as placing a reti() at the end of
>   the interrupt routine.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I'm inexperienced with AVR's assembly, so I guess I'll have to find some more info on preserving the sreg register.

Comment: it's easy enough to write a minimal example in C, compile it, look at the generated assembly listing, and copy it into your interrupt handler 'verbatim', augmented with a minimalist prologue and epilogue

Answer (score 3):

Are you planning to do anything else in the microprocessor, other than send the ADC readings? If not, forget using interrupts and just go with everything in the main loop. Interrupts are really only useful if you're trying to do something else in the "background".

Comment: "Interrupts are really [...] useful if you're trying to do something else in the "background"" ... or if you want/need to use power-saving features.

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother (yet) to use assembler. You don't need that.

However an important (general) point is: Don't call *blocking* functions from within an ISR! An ISR should *never* have to wait for *anything*.

Vicatcu is right: Use some kind of 'buffer', which can be as simple as a single global `uint16_t` variable, to which the ISR writes its result and the main loop picks it up when it can.

Another note: In your code you acquire an ADC result, send it out over the USART, and *then* start the next conversion. You should be able to get the ADC result, start the next conversion, and only *then* transfer the data, while the ADC is already processing the next sample at the same time. Or, you may want to look at the "free-running" mode of the ADC where it automatically starts the next conversion as soon as the previous one finished.

To illustrate how a generic buffering approach could be implemented, this may serve as an example:

```
volatile uint16_t adcValueBuffer;
volatile uint8_t adcValueBufferValidFlag;

ISR(ADC_vect) {

    adcValueBuffer = ADC;

    adcValueBufferValidFlag = 1; // This signals that the ADC provided a new value for the code outside the ISR.

    ADCSRA |= 1 << ADSC;

}


int main() {
  uint16_t adcValueCache; // Local variable which will hold the ADC value until it is completely transmitted.

  while( true ) {

    // Wait for the ISR to signal that a new value is available:
    while ( adcValueBufferValidFlag == 0 ) {
    }

    adcValueBufferValidFlag = 0; // Re-set flag. Will be set again by the ISR when a new ADC value becomes available.

    // Make sure that we read the buffered value atomically:
    cli();

    adcValueCache = adcValueBuffer;

    sei();

    USARTSendByte( (uint8_t)adcValueCache );
    USARTSendByte( (uint8_t)(adcValueCache >> 8));

  }

}
```

If/when the ADC is constantly sampling faster than the USART can transmit the data there's no way *not* to lose samples. In that case you'll need to synchronize both processes (sampling and transmitting) as you already did, starting the next sampling only *after* the (slower) transmission operation finishes.

Apart from that, *queues* or *circular buffers* (a.k.a. *ring buffers*) are often used to exchange data at varying rates between asynchronous components of the program: the ISR appends data to the buffer and the main-loop then takes (and removes) as many elements as are available in the buffer when it has the time.

These buffers can be implemented in two flavors regarding overflow conditions: one type discards any new data when the buffer is full, the other one just overwrites the oldest data in the buffer.

If that's what you need, just search for "avr circular buffer"; there are plenty of implementations out there.

Comment: Calling a function from an ISR is not bad by itself, but the function should not run longer than say some µs. The rule simply is: Keep the code that's run in an ISR as short as possible. -- You should not have to disable interrupts during transmission via USART, but, and I think that's your point, you should disable interrupts while reading the data provided by the ISR. You can easily 'cache' that data in `main()` like: `cli(); temp = adc_value; sei(); processAdcValue( temp );`

Comment: My USART transfer routine looks like this: `while ((UCSRA & (1 << UDRE)) == 0) {/*Do nothing*/} UDR = temp;`. So if an interrupt occurs _before_ the temp data is sent I will end up sending a different value due to `temp` being overwritten. This is actually why I wanted to disable the interrupts during data transfer.

Comment: Please have a look at my edit.

Comment: Thanks for the example. And also +1 for using Java naming conventions :) But I still have one more question: generally ADC runs faster than USART (for example ADC at 9.615ksps vs USART at 115200b/s). Does that mean that I should probably use a list (i.e. array) of ADC buffer variables in order not to loose some of the ADC samples?

Comment: Added another edit :)

Comment: thank's a lot for a very detailed and informative answer! It really helped me to sort things out.

Comment: That's great :) You may consider to *accept* my answer then.

Comment: I'd love to do that, but my initial question was "will interrupts decrease ADC performance", so I guess that accepting the answer would be unfair to @vicatcu :) I should have probably created another question about buffering ADC values. But once again, thanks for your time and effort, I really appreciate it.